# Quota error while creating GKE Autopilot Cluster. Insufficient regional quota: 300GB storage required while limit is 250GB

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

```
Error creating a deployment
Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB": 
request requires '300.0' and is short '50.0'.
project has a quota of '250.0' with '250.0' available.
```

This makes it impossible to create any GKE Autopilot cluster when in the free credits stage.

Is there a way to decrease the requested disk capacity to maybe 20G which is more than enough for my usecase.

Weird thing is that it was possible to create the same GKE Autopilot cluster just two months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates that the zone/region you're in has a limit of 250 GB and the quota is [exhausted](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters#pricing) now. You can read more about the type of disk quotas [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#disk_quota) and you can also request a [quota increase](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#about_increase_requests) if you want. In order to start up a cluster, you need at least 300 GB and I guess this is why we're seeing the requirement going to 300GB where the disk-size defaults to 100GB.

This is the default behavior of the [GKE autopilot](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-overview#allowable_resource_ranges). **There is no way to decrease the requested disk capacity to 20GB. But you can follow below workarounds, which may help to resolve your issue** :

**Workaround 1** : By changing the default SSD disk to a Standard Persistent Disk it may work. For more details follow the official [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance).

**Workaround 2** :  If you believe that 300GB is more than what you actually require, you can scale back or restrict the resources requested. For your reference see the official GCP [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-resource-requests#resource-limits)  on how to place a limit on resources.

In my opinion, having a basic (Standard) GKE cluster is preferable than Autopilot, which offers less managing alternatives. In cases where price is extremely low, it is preferable to use [Preemptible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W9bGq.png) nodes in the GKE cluster.

Comment: About Workaround 1: Aren't the SSD Disks that Autopilot provisions ephemeral ones? Can you actually change these disks to standard ephemeral ones and not persistent ones.