# Standard mistake whereas making GKE Autopilot Cluster. Deficiently territorial quantity: 300GB capacity required whereas constrain is 250GB

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autopilot

`Error creating a deployment Insufficient regional quota to satisfy request: resource "SSD_TOTAL_GB":  request requires '300.0' and is short '50.0'. project has a quota of '250.0' with '250.0'`  
I'm unable to create autopilot cluster getting above error

Learning purpose Trying to create cluster but not working

I want to resolve this error

Advance thanks help me in this issue

Comment: You must request a quota increase for persistent disks or switch to a region that has enough disk quota. If your account is brand new and you are not a business, the request will not be approved until you have several months of payment history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting indicates that the zone/region you're in has a limit of 250 GB and the quota is [exhausted](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/regional-clusters#pricing) now

**You can follow any of this below workarounds**

1. It might work if you change the SSD disk that comes installed to a Standard Persistent Disk. For additional subtleties follow the authority [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/performance).
2. You can reduce the amount of resources requested or limit it if you think 300GB is more than you need. The official GCP [document](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/autopilot-resource-requests#resource-limits) on how to limit resources is available for your review.

**Note:**

**You can read more about the type of [disk quotas](https://cloud.google.com/compute/resource-usage#disk_quota) here and you can also request a [quota increase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77363580/quota-error-while-creating-gke-autopilot-cluster-insufficient-regional-quota-3/77365011#77365011:%7E:text=also%20request%20a-,quota%20increase,-if%20you%20want) if you want  but Johnhanley mentioned  If your account is brand new and you are not a business, the request will not be approved until you have several months of payment history.**

I’m suggesting  you to go with   a basic (Standard) GKE cluster over Autopilot, which offers fewer management options which  is best for learning purpose